# Labelling Max coverage by Area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, overlapping-features, pivot-table

I'm struggling to find a quick way to identify and label an area by the maximum coverage of an overlapping polygon. Has anyone done a process like this lately? 
I'm currently playing with the Pivot table, but the machine is still processing, and I'm not sure if the Pivot Table is the answer, yet.
I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

[image: Diagram showing postcode covering the largest area within the zone of interest]

[image: How the attribute table looks.]

Comment: What license level do you have access to?  If you have Standard, you can use the [Tabulate Intersection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000044000000) tool.  That may or may not be what you're looking for.  If you don't have Standard, there are ways around it, but the steps are longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Maplex labelling engine, go into the label properties of your layer.  Go to label density tab; Tick 'remove duplicates' at the top and tick 'Label largest feature part' at the bottom.  This will force the label engine to only label the larger section of each CATCHMENT_ID.

[image]